# How do I grep for foo && !bar?

Tags: unix, grep, xargs

I want to output all the lines in my source code which contain the string `foo` but don't contain the string `bar`.  I tried this:

```
find . -name "*.[hc]pp" | xargs grep -n foo | grep -x bar
```

However this doesn't work as I expected. How can I use grep in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `-v` flag, not the `-x` flag.

Mnemonic: negati**v**e.

Comment: that did it - tyvm!  lmao: I had the wrong mnemonic: eXclude